# A reset problem on a RCA, Android tablet

Tags: factory-reset

I was given 2 used 7" RCA model RCT6873W42 Android tablets. The batterys on both tablets are charged up and the tablets turn on. The last owner didn't do the "wipe data/factory reset" in the right order. They didn't remove the last Gmail account that the tablets were sync to before doing the factory reset.  And I keep running into a roadblock on both tablets when I get to the point in the set up were it asks for my Google email address. See the [screen capture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmpy8zarpi5l4s2/rca%20tablet%20error.jpg?dl=0). I did the "wipe data/factory reset" 2 times. No change. I don't know how to bypass the "Factory Reset Protection" and I can't get the last owner's email address and password in order to open up the tablets. Is there a way to around the "Factory Reset Protection"?

Steve

Update I now have what the eBay seller calls an "OEM MICRO USB male to female USB OTG Host Adapter For a RCA Voyager RCT6873W42 Tablet". I must be doing something wrong in trying to get the tablet to see the prog "Bypass any Samsung Google Account Lock.apk" or I am using the wrong APK prog.

Also I have found that I have full access via a back door to all non rooted files and directory's in the tablet via the USB cable when connected to my Windows laptop. What I can do with that back door, I don't know. But I can read and write to the tablets. I also have ADB/Fastload for windows. I have used ADB/Fastload to root a cell phone and a tablet before. But that cell phone and tablet didn't have FRP installed in them. They were older OS's.

Comment: The post [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)  by Andy Yan] is for a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge cell phone. What I have are tablets. These tablets CAN NOT be used to make calls even to 911

Comment: Did you read through all the methods? Not all methods necessitate a dialer. Also, that post is a general pointer to this type of question - to prevent being flagged as a duplicate of it, try the solutions posted in there and edit your question to reflect how they wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing their Google account in settings?

To remove a Google account, go to settings, then either Google (Or accounts). If prompted, tap the account name. Tap MORE. Tap Remove account. Tap REMOVE ACCOUNT to confirm.

If they have a passcode or screen pattern then you'll have to find a way around it. But if not then that should help.

Comment: FRP happens in Setup Wizard where you wouldn't have access to Settings or any other app (unless worked around by an exploit - but then again you still need the original account's password to be able to remove it).

Comment: I don't have access to the "original Gmail account that the tablets were sync to"  And I have to wait for payday to buy a  USB-OTG cable.

Comment: I got the USB-OTG cable. The tablets won't see the USB-OTG cable. I am about ready to take these tablets out for TP